# Как работает pow() в С++?

Tags: c++, функции

Решил глянуть код С++ -ного `pow()` . Как это работает?

```
_Check_return_ inline double pow(_In_ double _Xx, _In_ int _Yx) noexcept
    {
    if (_Yx == 2)
        return (_Xx * _Xx);

    return (_CSTD pow(_Xx, static_cast<double>(_Yx)));
    }
```

А конкретно эта строка:

```
(_CSTD pow(_Xx, static_cast<double>(_Yx)))
```

`static_cast<double>(_Yx)`- это приведение к типу `double`

А что такое `_CSTD`?
И что такое `_In_`?
Код CSTD:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 #define _CSTD  ::

 #define _EXTERN_C          extern "C" {
 #define _END_EXTERN_C      }
#else /* ^^^ __cplusplus ^^^ // vvv !__cplusplus vvv */
 #define _CSTD

 #define _EXTERN_C
 #define _END_EXTERN_C
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_In_` - это аннотация [SAL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=vs-2017)

`_CSTD` - это макрос раскрывающийся в обращение к глобальному пространству имен `::`

`pow` - это вызов реализации `pow` из С

Comment: "`pow`- это вызов реализации `pow` из С", умно, действительно зачем писать два раза. Правда выглядит как рекурсия.

Comment: @AwesomeMan А многие С++ функции из пространства `std` просто вызывают соответствующие функции из C просто предоставляя больше перегрузок.

Answer (score -2):

Какой-то макрос, зависящий от реализации. Смысл в том, что если на вход даётся значение интегрального типа, то вызываем перегрузку для типа `double`

_In_, скорее всего, макрос или алиас для спецификаторов типа (например, const)

Ну вот, теперь сразу видно что это `::`

```
#define _CSTD  ::
```

Comment: а потом что? макрос возводит в степень?

Comment: @AwesomeMan функция `pow(double, double)` возводит в степень, макрос может использоваться для чего угодно, приведите его код

Comment: @AwesomeMan как вариант, может указывать пространство имён `std::` или другое